# Cannot convert method group to Action

Tags: c#

I am stuck with this error but not sure how to fix it.

I am trying to pass a method as a parameter to another function as an action. I have an interface which defines two methods:

```
//ISegment interface
void SetNodeA(in INode node);
void SetNodeB(in INode node);
```

Next I create a segment and I want to pass this method into another function:

```
ISegment segment = GetSegment();
Execute(start, segment.SetNodeA);
Execute(end, segment.SetNodeB);
```

My execute function looks like this:

```
void Execute(in EndPoint point, in Action<INode> fnc)
{
    Verify(segment);
    Verify(point.Node);
    fnc?.Invoke(point.Node); //set the node
}
```

Problem is i get this error:

> Argument 2: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'in Action'

Not sure what it means by method group here or how to fix it.

Comment: Do you have a good reason for using `in` in your `ISegment` methods?  I ask because if you remove them your code will work fine.

Comment: Oh thats the reason. I use `in` a lot as a habit to strictly enforce that it cannot be changed. It just makes me less prone for mistakes. How come it won't allow `in` ?

Comment: @WDUK `in` with interfaces for such reason is pointless, cause interface without generics will be always treated as reference type and you can't change incoming reference (so it is observed by the caller) if you don't use special modifier.

Comment: Ah, I understand that reason, but unfortunately that is not the primary purpose of the `in` keyword here.  It is meant to allow you to pass values by reference (like `ref` and `out`) but not allow you to modify the parameter.  From MSFT: "Add the in modifier to pass an argument by reference and declare your design intent to pass arguments by reference to avoid unnecessary copying. You don't intend to modify the object used as that argument."  But why that breaks generics type inference is a good question.

Comment: Oh so using `in` on reference types is largely pointless. Okay now i understand! Thanks :)

Comment: @KirkWoll why do you believe that?

Comment: @WDUK yes, you will still be able to modify the instance itself and `in` parameter does not prevent that.

Comment: @KirkWoll _"But why that breaks generics type inference is a good question. "_ AFAIK  it does not, the issue is that `Action` and `Func` does not support passing parameter by reference.

Comment: @KirkWoll what I wrote is about `in` parameter modifier.

Comment: @GuruStron, ah, my apologies.  When you said, "cause interface without generics will be always treated as reference type" I thought you were referring to the `ISegment` inteface, not the `INode` interface.  But I understand now.  I'll delete my erroneous comments.

Comment: @KirkWoll No problem. My wording/explanation was far from perfect. I meant the case when `Get<T>(in T t) where T : ISegment` - in this case if `T` is value type implementing `ISegment` then `in` can make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your `SetNodeA` and `SetNodeB` methods have an `in` parameter *and* you're trying to invoke them via an `Action<T>`, which does *not* support `in`, `out`, or `ref` parameters.

If you need to keep using `in` for those methods, then you can achieve that by creating a custom delegate type and use that instead of `Action<T>`:

```
public delegate void ActionWithInParam<T>(in T node);
```

Then, your `Execute` method would be something like this:

```
void Execute(in EndPoint point, ActionWithInParam<INode> fnc)
{
    Verify(segment);
    Verify(point.Node);
    fnc?.Invoke(point.Node); //set the node
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need either remove `in` parameter modifier from `SetNodeX` signature or use custom delegate for second `Execute` parameter:

```cs
public interface ISegment
{
    void SetNodeA(in INode node);
    void SetNodeB(INode node); // in removed
}

public delegate void DelegateWithIn(in INode node);

void Execute(in EndPoint point, DelegateWithIn fnc)
{
}
void Execute1(in EndPoint point, Action<INode> fnc)
{
}

Execute(null, segment.SetNodeA); // uses custom delegate
Execute1(null, segment.SetNodeB); // uses Action
```

As I mentioned in the comments `Action` and `Func` delegates does not support `in`, `out` and `ref` parameter modifiers.